# MySQL rows, apart from last row, are indented and not searchable? (LOAD DATA INFILE)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm loading a simple CSV file into a MySQL DB using the LOAD DATA INFILE feature using...

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '../../htdocs/aspens/files/thefile.csv'
                INTO TABLE students
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

The query works succesfully and provides me with the following table...

```
+----------------+---------+
| student_name   | class   |
+----------------+---------+
 |Aaaaaaaaa aaaa | Year 1
 |Bbbb Bbbbbb    | Year 2
 |Cccc Ccccccc   | Year 3
 |Ddddddd Dddddd | Year 4
| Eeee Eeeee     | Year 4  |
+----------------+---------+
```

When I've attempted to then search this database, I'm only able to search the last row that is inserted, this is regardless of the total row count of the table, it is only the last row I'm able to search.

For example..

```
SELECT * FROM students;
```

works and produces me the table above.

However, if I do the following...

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE class='Year 4";
```

Only the final entry comes up, and if I do

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE class='Year 3";
```

The table returns nothing, this includes if I search using `LIKE '"%Year 4%"'`

I'm assuming the indent in my rows is a hint at what could be going wrong here, but everything in phpadmin looks fine?

EDIT:

CSV file is as follows..

```
Student Name,Class Name
Aaaaaaaaa aaaa,Year 1
Bbbb Bbbbbb,Year 2
Cccc Ccccccc,Year 3
Ddddddd Dddddd,Year 4
Eeee Eeeee ,Year 4
```

Comment: If you have generated the csv file on a Windows system, you might have to use LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n', otherwise you might end up with trailing carriage returns.

Comment: @Danijel Who knew something so simple could be so annoying! Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Danijel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2352773/danijel) pointed out, as the csv file had been generated on a Windows system (in my case, on a Mac but used Microsoft Excel) I needed to take into account for carriage returns.

Unix uses \n

Mac uses just a carriage return \r

Windows uses \r\n